# Can we create a common screen to handle all type of exceptions in Android?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am thinking to create a mechanism to handle all type of exception and show a common screen instead of the error to user of the application. Such type of handling is possible in web development but is it possible on Android application development?

I would be nice idea if we don't need to write code on each Activity or screen to handle all type of exception.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In **catch** redirect the caught exception to the desired activity where
all exceptions are described. Match the caught exception & done..

Comment: Ok, but we have to write code on each screen to catch the exception. Can we do it on Application level

Comment: You definitely have to catch the exception first. I m not sure whether application level exist. catch -> send -> receive -> match !

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create a class which implements UncaughtExceptionHandler

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public ExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, final Throwable e) {
        //[...]
        //Handle your Exception here
    }
}
```

You then need to register 'ExceptionHandler' using:

```
ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
```

All Exceptions which are not explicitly catched by a try-catch and occur in a Thread which has the ExceptionHandler registered will be automatically redirected to your UncaughtExceptionHandler.